# How to plot from stdin multiple times in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

The data input from stdin fails for the second time as follows, how can I solve this problem?

```
plot '-' w l
0 0
5 0
e
replot '-' w l
       ^
unexpected or unrecognized token
```

replot after data input from stdin also fails

```
plot '-' w l
0 0
5 0
e
replot sin(x)
       ^
unexpected or unrecognized token
```

The following code works, so I don't know what's the problem.

```
plot sin(x)
replot '-' w l
0 0
5 0
e
```

I know `plot '-' w l, '-' w l` will draw multiple lines. But I'm using gnuplot from the program and I don't have all data to plot in advance. So I can't use this method.
I think I can solve this problem by writing the results of the process to a file, but can't I do that from stdin? I want to plot incrementally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this is by using a datablock rather than the pseudo-file '-'.   Here is what the input stream to gnuplot should look like.

```
# Begin input
$DATA1 << EOD
1 2
3 4
EOD

plot $DATA1 with lines

$DATA2 << EOD
5 6 
7 8
EOD

replot $DATA2
# or I would actually prefer
plot $DATA1 with lines, $DATA2 with lines
```

Comment: It looks nice. Thank you very much.